# Can i Create appdelegate object in .c file in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to create object of delegate file in my .c file and try to access appDelegate file image string there.. can i?? Or i am going wrong???

Answer (score 1):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (void)someMethod
{
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   imageString = appDelegate.imageStringName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* do that, you then need to tell Xcode that your `.c` file should be compiled as an Objective-C file because you have written some Objective-C specific code in it. You should rename the file to `.m`: it's easier and in the future it'll be more obvious that it contains ObjC code.